# Can't install pyrealsense2 on Windows 10 using pip

Tags: python, opencv, pip, computer-vision

I tried to install pyrealsense2 using pip in VS Code with the command `pip install pyrealsense2`.
However, VS Code prints following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyrealsense2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyrealsense2
```

I am using Windows 10 and Python 3.10. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Python libraries are install through the windows powershell or CMD,

Run CMD, then paste this command

```
pip install pyrealsense2
```

then press enter, wait for it to install. Once it is done just restart VS Code

Comment: I did it through windows powershell (in the VS Code terminal), but I get the same error everywhere

Comment: try using CMD (not through VS Code terminal) aka cmd.exe

Comment: I did that too, same result

Comment: try installing the files here https://pypi.org/project/pyrealsense2/#files

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Had to finish work earlier. I tried but, when I try to install the package using ```pip install [path]``` I get following error:

```ERROR: pyrealsense2-2.51.1.4348-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.```

Comment: try this command `py -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel` and check this site https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/

Comment: Doesn't work either, I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

`pyrealsense2` is only available up to Python version `3.9` See https://pypi.org/project/pyrealsense2/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).